# Get all Entities from Dynamics365 with code

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am trying to retrieve all entities from Dynamics 365 with code.
Currently I am using RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest like this:

```
var metaDataRequest = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest();               
metaDataRequest.EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes;
metaDataRequest.RetrieveAsIfPublished = true;
var metaDataResponse = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse)organizationProxy.Execute(metaDataRequest);
```

This code retrieves over 400 entities.
My problem is that I only want to get the ones listed as Entities in the "Customize the System" dialog as shown in the picture below. Like Account, Activity, Address, Appointment.

The code I use returns entities like: accountleads, aciviewmapper,actioncardusersettings and I am not interested in those!
I have tried looking through the EntityMetadata values but that did not give any clues to my problem.

[image: Customize the System - Dialog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally we will keep a list of entity names in array to pull the Metadata instead of pulling everything.

Let's try this. I have used XrmToolBox - Metadata browser plugin to find out a common filter to use in your code, so that you will get the entity list only you want.

`IsCustomizable`, `CanChangeTrackingBeEnabled`, `CanCreateViews`, `CanModifyAdditionalSettings` gave me the hint we need. Dig more in this direction if you see a common criteria for your need.

[image]